# Nodejs post request

Tags: angularjs, node.js, authentication, request, http-post

I am trying to login to a website with the following request:

```
var request = require('request');

var options = {
method: 'POST',
url: 'https://server/EnterpriseController',
params: {a: 1},
form: "actionType=authenticateUser&reqObj=[null,username,password,null,1]",
headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'

},
withCredentials: true,
rejectUnauthorized: false
};

request(options,
function (error, response, body, data) {

    if (request.method === 'POST') {
        var body = '';
        request.on('data', function (data) {
            body += data;
        });
        request.on('end', function () {
            var post = qs.parse(body);
        });
    }
    console.log(body);
}
);
```

I am always getting an error. I think the form is wrong but I have the same login on an angularjs site without any error. I don't understand why the login works on angularjs site but not in nodejs.

```
 )]}',
 {"login_err": true, "resp": [null,null,null,1]
 }
```

Comment: Just wanted to remind you that you have added the password in your code example (in case that was not on purpose)

Comment: Thanks Andreas. I missed that because nobody can connect without the vpn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed the cookie:/ And the Formdata should be an Object.